# how to access ZFS UNIX command line

Tags: command-line, zfs

It seems to be super easy but I just can´t get into it! All I have is the ´cli´, well documented. But I can´t execute commands like `zpool`, `zfs` etc.

How do I get there?

Thanks

Comment: Which OS are you using? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @mtak the ZFS os is the default one. I am using the oracle template zfs virtual machine. All I have as command line is the integrated cli. But I read everywhere people using bash commands, I just don't know how to reach it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was actually different.

Just type `confirm shell` in the cli and you get it. However, it instantly breaks oracle warranty if you type anything else than `exit` in there.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the comments, you are using the Oracle ZFS Storage Appliance. This appliance is a demo of the (ex) Fishworks product and is meant to be used through the integrated CLI and web UI. You will not be able to use the standard ZFS commands (well, you could hack the appliance, but that's not what it was designed for).

If you want to have a traditional ZFS setup, either install Solaris 11, OpenIndiana or FreeBSD. These OS'es have ZFS built in and will allow you to manage it using the `zpool` and `zfs` commands.